# Shouldn't we do A/B test on popular question?

Tags: discussion

Here is our site popular question - [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Here we can change our title to do A/B test in terms of organic traffic changes.

For example we can change our title to "How to improve your site ranking on Google?" may give us better organic traffic then old one title.

Comment: An A/B test requires that you try both variants at the same time and be able to accurately measure results.   We can't do either.  I think your suggested title would be fine.  I don't like the word "best" in the title anyway, but I don't think it is something we can A/B test.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by same time, but I am thinking to change some popular post(Specially community wiki question) title for few month and if it return good amount of traffic then keep the title as it is. With time we need to change something, because I don't think now people type query like "How to increase my site position?" instead they more often type "how to improve my site ranking?".

Comment: I'm just questioning the need for testing and the feasibility of doing so. I'd suggest that you make a suggestion for new titles and we can decide if we want to change them based on whether we like them.   Getting traffic to those questions isn't really the goal anyway.   The catch-all questions are places to direct users that ask things that would otherwise be off-topic.

Comment: The more traffic we get, the more people know about this community and more people join us. I also discover this great place from search. Anyway where I can give my suggestion to change title, here in meta stackexchange or in chat discussion? I can edit the question directly but I can't do it without knowing what other community member thinks about it. Here people like you contributing this community from a long time, I am newbie here. So It's not right to edit the title without taking advice from you guys.

Comment: Traffic is nice, but we get the majority of our traffic to other questions.   Better titles are always nice if they describe it more succinctly and use keywords better.    The only reason I would have not to change the titles of our catch-all questions would be that we close things as duplicate of them all the time.  Those of us who do so know the current titles and search for the questions by those titles.   Some of us might have a harder time finding the catch-all questions for a bit until we got used to it.

Comment: OK.......... :)